# Javascript Pre-defined Function

Tags: javascript

```
function processForm() {

    var temperature = document.tempForm.temp.value;

}
```

According to designed button,I want to take temperature value from text field and to convert numeric value then store it in variable "temperature" that I defined.

JavaScript has a built-in function called Number(). It converts the value in parentheses to a number that can be used in calculations. If it is not a number, it will return NaN (Not a Number).

How can I do this?

Comment: How can you do what? I *think* you want: `var temperature = parseInt(document.tempForm.temp.value, 10);` but I'm unsure, from your description.

Comment: Will this work? `+document.tempForm.temp.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temperature = temperature *1;
```

or

```
temperature = +temperature;
```

temperature will be NaN if it is not a number

Comment: If you want to cast something to `Number`, `+stringVariable` is sufficient.